# Cpu vs Gpu for programming laptop

Tags: laptop, computer-building

Wich laptop is better for programming

1.Specs: 
Cpu: i7 6500u (quad core)
Gpu: nvidia gtx950m 
Ram: 8gb ram 
Ssd: 256gb

2.Specs 
Cpu: i5 6300hq (quad core)
Gpu: nvidia gtx960m 
Ram: 8gb ram 
Ssd: 256gb

Comment: This is off-topic because it's a hardware recommendation question. We can migrate it to [Hardware Recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) if you'd like.

Comment: This probably won't meet the quality guidelines for [hardwarerecs.se] as it currently stands. You can find their guidelines in their help centre if you decide to ask there: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

It depends. It completely depends on what you're programming. If you are programming apps or need to use programming tools that require higher resource usage then I'd go with #1 and even go up to 16 GB ram.

BUT, in general, both are perfectly fine. You can even get a laptop with lower spec and it should be fine.

Again, it depends.

Oh, and GPU only matter if you are programming graphics related software. I mean, do you need good graphics card to develop a servlet? No.

Comment: I use android studio, intelij idea for libgdx and java, kali linux virtual machine this what i use the most

Comment: I use my android phone to test apps

Comment: @programmerwannabe I'd personally say option 2. It has a GPU that is a step up from the first one, and the CPU is a quad core rather than a dual core.

Comment: That i7 is tempting because it is i7 but gpu is better in second option

Comment: I want it to be fast

Comment: Yeah, in that case, I think either CPU should be fine since they are both quad core, and, I think either GPU should be sufficient as well. If you are running several IDE's and VM's then I'd rather recommend you'd go up on the RAM to 16GB.

Comment: There is a free ram slot